# quanteda, how to keep one or few words from the stopwords list for my analysis

Tags: r

How can I keep one o few words from the list of stopwords for my analysis.  This means not to use it as stopwords and allow them in my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to remove the words "cuando" and "pero" from the Spanish stopwords list, you can create your own stopword list where they are not included.

```
new_stopwords <- stopwords::stopwords(language = "es")

list_to_exclude <- c("cuando", "pero")

new_stopwords <- new_stopwords[!new_stopwords %in% list_to_exclude]
```

Next you can use quanteda as you normally would, and use the `new_stopwords` list to remove stopwords.